# Operator qubit ordering not matching circuit qubit ordering

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, density-matrix

I tried constructing a `cx` gate manually using tensor products and one using `QuantumCircuit` in qiskit followed by converting it to an `Operator`. The matrix from `Operator` does not match the manual construction, I believe this is due to the swap in the ordering of the qubits.

```python
def test1():
    oneone = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1]])
    zerozero = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]])
    eye = np.identity(2)

    unitary = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])

    cx = np.kron(zerozero, eye) + np.kron(oneone, unitary)

    op_auto = UnitaryGate(unitary).control(1, ctrl_state='1')

    qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2)
    # Passes only due to reversed ordering of qubits.
    qc1.append(op_auto, [1, 0])
    op_auto = Operator.from_circuit(qc1)

    op_manual = UnitaryGate(cx)
    qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
    qc2.append(op_manual, [0, 1])
    op_manual = Operator.from_circuit(qc2)

    npt.assert_array_almost_equal(op_auto.data, op_manual.data)
```

Is there a way to force the layout to match the ordering of my choice? I did look into the `layout` parameter of the `Operator.from_circuit` method but I do not understand how to use it, there isn't any relevant documentation attached to the interface document either. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: What would be the more general situation you'd want to adjust ordering for? In this case just flipping the order of both Kronecker products would serve the same purpose as flipping the 2nd append argument.

Comment: I am trying to apply a controlled version of a 3-8 qubit unitary that I am constructing with 1 qubit control. It doesn't match the output I'd get from doing the Kronecker product, which is what I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using numpy's Kronecker product, you can use [Operator's tensor product](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/02_operators_overview.html#Tensor-Product). (Not better, just another way to do it):

```
oneone : Operator = Operator(np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1]]))
zerozero : Operator = Operator(np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]]))
eye : Operator = Operator(np.identity(2))
unitary : Operator = Operator(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]))

cx_UGate : UnitaryGate = zerozero.tensor(eye) + oneone.tensor(unitary)

qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc2.append(cx_UGate, [0, 1])
op_manual = Operator.from_circuit(qc2)

print(op_manual)
```

Where **the output is correct**:

```
Operator([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
      [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
      [0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
      [0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]],
     input_dims=(2, 2), output_dims=(2, 2))
```

$$\begin{split}CX =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$

Note that  **your way is also correct**. I think **the problem is on op_auto (its output is weird)**. You can do:

```
CXGate().to_matrix()
```

Note: this is in **little endian convention**, so we need to change the definition of CX:

$$\begin{split}CX\ q_0, q_1 =
I \otimes |0\rangle\langle0| + X \otimes |1\rangle\langle1| =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$

And so, our code:

```
oneone : Operator = Operator(np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1]]))
zerozero : Operator = Operator(np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]]))
eye : Operator = Operator(np.identity(2))
unitary : Operator = Operator(np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]))

cx_UGate : UnitaryGate = eye.tensor(zerozero) + unitary.tensor(oneone)

qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc2.append(cx_UGate, [0, 1])
op_manual = Operator.from_circuit(qc2)

print(CXGate().to_matrix()==op_manual.data)
```

And the output:

```
[[ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
```

I recomend you also to change some name variables, such as unitary (being a Pauli X gate) and so.

So, the final code:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator, Pauli
from qiskit.extensions import CXGate, UnitaryGate

class CX:
    oneone : Operator = Operator(np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1]]))
    zerozero : Operator = Operator(np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]]))

    def __cx_little_endian(self) -> UnitaryGate:
        return Operator(Pauli('I')).tensor(self.zerozero) + Operator(Pauli('X')).tensor(self.oneone)

    def __cx_big_endian(self) -> UnitaryGate:
        return self.zerozero.tensor(Operator(Pauli('I'))) + self.oneone.tensor(Operator(Pauli('X')))

    def cx(self, is_little_endian = True) -> UnitaryGate:
        return self.__cx_little_endian() if is_little_endian else self.__cx_big_endian()

cx_obj : CX = CX()
qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc2.append(cx_obj.cx(), [0, 1])
op_manual = Operator.from_circuit(qc2)

print(cx_obj.cx(True))
print(cx_obj.cx(False))
print(CXGate().to_matrix()==op_manual.data)
```

If, somehow, I do not understand the question, please comment the issue and I'll try to answer again the best I can :) .

### Edit

Hi! I just see your comment and here is the edit.

First of all, the UnitaryGate:

```
cx_gate = UnitaryGate(XGate()).control(1)
```

Nevertheless, you can use other formats:

```
cx_gate = XGate().control(1)
```

If we want to check on big endian notation, we can make use of `reverse_bits()`, a QuantumCircuit method, so here is the code (with the CX class):

```
class CX:
    oneone : Operator = Operator(np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1]]))
    zerozero : Operator = Operator(np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]]))

    def __cx_little_endian(self) -> UnitaryGate:
        return Operator(Pauli('I')).tensor(self.zerozero) + Operator(Pauli('X')).tensor(self.oneone)

    def __cx_big_endian(self) -> UnitaryGate:
        return self.zerozero.tensor(Operator(Pauli('I'))) + self.oneone.tensor(Operator(Pauli('X')))
    #NEW
    def is_cx(self, op_cx: Operator, is_little_endian = True) -> bool:
        return op_cx == self.cx(is_little_endian)
    
    def cx(self, is_little_endian = True) -> UnitaryGate:
        return self.__cx_little_endian() if is_little_endian else self.__cx_big_endian()


# CODE EXAMPLE 
cx_obj : CX = CX()
cx_gate = UnitaryGate(XGate()).control(1)
qc : QuantumCircuit = QuantumCircuit(2)

qc.append(cx_gate, [0,1])
print(cx_obj.is_cx(Operator.from_circuit(qc.reverse_bits()),is_little_endian=False))
```

Where the output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I was hoping there was a way for me to use the `control` method on the unitary gate and append it to the circuit AND still be able to get the non-endian operator that you have constructed. Your solution was still helpful, it would be great if you are aware of getting non-endian operator after using `control` method :D

Comment: @Zeeshanahmed Done :)